# Why does nginx proxy_pass close my connection?

Tags: http, nginx, proxypass

The documentation says the following

> Sets the HTTP protocol version for proxying. By default, version 1.0 is used. Version 1.1 is recommended for use with keepalive connections and NTLM authentication.

In my nginx config I have

```
    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1980;
    }
```

Doing http://127.0.0.1:1980 directly I can see my app get many request (when I refresh) on one connection. This is the response I send

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type:text/html\nContent-Length: 14\nConnection: keep-alive\n\nHello World!

However nginx makes one request and closes it. WTH? I can see nginx sends the "Connection: keep-alive" header. I can see it added the server and date header. I tried adding `proxy_set_header Connection "keep-alive";` but that didn't help.

How do I get nginx to not close the connection every thread?

Answer (score 35):

In order Nginx to keep connection alive, the following configuration is required:

- Configure appropriate headers (HTTP 1.1 and Connection header does not contain "Close" value, the actual value doesn't matter, Keep-alive or just an empty value)
- Use upstream block with keepalive instruction, just proxy_pass url won't work
- Origin server should have keep-alive enabled

So the following Nginx configuration makes keepalive working for you:

```
upstream keepalive-upstream {
  server 127.0.0.1:1980;
  keepalive 64;
}

server { 
  location / { 
    proxy_pass http://keepalive-upstream;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
  } 
}
```

Make sure, your origin server doesn't finalise the connection, according to [RFC-793 Section 3.5](http://freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1122/99.htm):

> A TCP connection may terminate in two ways: (1) the normal TCP close
> sequence using a FIN handshake, and (2) an "abort" in which one or
> more RST segments are sent and the connection state is immediately
> discarded. If a TCP connection is closed by the remote site, the local
> application MUST be informed whether it closed normally or was
> aborted.

A bit more details can be found in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419976/default-value-of-nginx-keepalive/46614442#46614442) on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Is it possible to have upstream keepalive **without** an ```upstream``` block?  I have a situation where we're dynamically assigning the proxy_pass value based upon a variable (e.g. ```proxy_pass https://$new_server:$new_port;```.

Comment: @DropPhone did you ever figure out an answer to your question? I am wondering the same?

Comment: What does the `keepalive 64;` do? is 64 the time to keep the connection alive?

Comment: @LibbyLebyane it's the "maximum number of idle keepalive connections to upstream servers", see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive

Comment: Is `upstream { ... }` a syntactically valid directive? Must there not be a *name* between the word `upstream` and the opening bracket?

Comment: Despite what the docs say, shouldn't that line actually be `proxy_set_header Connection "keep-alive"`? Though HTTP/1.1 says keep-alive is the default behavior, popular clients such as browsers or Postman will send the "Connection: keep-alive" header regardless. I believe this is to avoid cases where the server doesn't adhere to spec and sends back "Connection: close" unless it receives an explicit "Connection: keep-alive" from the client, so would it hurt to do so here?

Answer (score 9):

keepalive should enable in upstream block, not direct proxy_pass http://ip:port.

For HTTP, the proxy_http_version directive should be set to “1.1” and the “Connection” header field should be cleared

like this:

```
upstream keepalive-upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:1980;
    keepalive 23;
}

 location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection ""; 
    proxy_pass http://keepalive-upstream;
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that an upstream server may also elect to close the connection.  This can happen when a 50x error is encountered.  A packet capture can show you if this is the case.

Comment: Can proxy_http_version 1.1; and proxy_set_header Connection ""; be put in the http block and then apply to all contained location blocks, or do they have to be in each individual location block.