# Angular App with Data in the URL gets 404 from NGINX

Tags: angular, nginx, configuration, single-page-application

I have a server with this setup:

In the root (/var/www) folder I have an `index.html` that links to angular **app1** and **app2**

```
   \index.html
   |
   +-\app1\index.html
   |
   +-\app2\index.html
```

My angular app2 has data in the `URL` so my `URL` will look like this:

```
https://www.example.com/app2/thispartisdata/AlongDataStringThatContainsData
```

When I browse to `https://www.example.com/app2`  everything works fine

When I browse to `https://www.example.com/app2/somedata` this goes to a `404` message from `NGINX`

I have tried the `try_files` configuration option but I only need it for my second app.

So what I would like to do is something like this (but I can't figure out or find what the syntax would be or if it's even possible)

```
location /app2 {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app2/index.html;
}
```

I can't get the above to work. I want to have requests to **app2** pass the entire `URL` on to **app2** and not have `NGINX` get in the way and return a `404`. I can't find the correct way to have ONLY **app2** receive the full URLs and redirect that full `URL` to **app2's** `index.html`.

**Edit**

My full configuration:

```
server {

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location /app1/api/ {
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:5001;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       }

        location /app2/api/ {
                proxy_read_timeout 300s;
                proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:5002/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_request_buffering off;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

# I want to do something like this here, but this give a 500 error
#
#        location /app2 {
#             try_files $uri /app2/index.html;
#        }

        location / {
                root /var/www;
                index index.html;
        }


    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



        server_name example.com www.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: Your configuration looks ok (however I'd prefer `location /app2/ { try_files $uri /app2/index.html; }`). The only reason I can guess is that your URI with data gets processed with some other location or gets rewritten by some server-level rewrite rule. Can you show your full nginx config?

Comment: Your configuration is a really weird one. Looks like some parts were taken from the config supposed to support WebSocket, but other parts are screwing that support. One of your `proxy_pass` directives is `proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:5001;` and the other is `proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:5002/;` Do you understand how drastically differs those two and what is the difference? And since the only `root` directive you have is inside the `location / { ... }` no wonder you got an endless redirect loop with your `location /app2 { ... }`

Comment: I am an extreme NGINX novice, so theres definitely a lot about it that I don't understand. So I have two .net APIs running on my server (one listening on port 5001, and another listening on port 5002) that I want to pass requests to, so this configuration is trying to do that, so far it's working. The apis are getting their requests, and the angular applications that go with them are also working, except for my stated problem.

Comment: I don't think it is your only error, but at least move your `root` directive one level up, to the server context. Next, try `location /app2/ { try_files $uri /app2/index.html; }`

Comment: Nice that seems to have worked!

Comment: @IvanShatsky if you add your comment as the answer I will accept it so you get the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main mistake here is that you didn't defined the `root` for your web site at the `server` level. Your `root /var/www;` is being effective only in the `location / { ... }` and not anywhere else. Like many other nginx directives the `root` directive, if not being inherited from the previous configuration levels, has a default value of `/html` relative to the nginx *prefix*. That prefix is specified during the build time and can be checked with the `nginx -V` command (see the `--prefix=...` configure argument). If by example this prefix is equal to `/etc/nginx` (a common case), the default server webroot will be `/etc/nginx/html`. You need to move that directive one level up, to the `server` context instead of `location` one.

After doing that, you can add

```
location /app2/ {
    try_files $uri /app2/index.html;
}
```

to your `server` block. I don't use an `$uri/` component here since I do not expect you have any nested `index.html` under your **app2** web app directory other than `/app2/index.html` one. Redirect from `/app2` to `/app2/` will be made by nginx automatically since under your `location / { ... }` an implicit `try_files $uri $uri/ =404` will be used as the default `PRECONTENT` request processing phase handler, and the `/app2` request will be handled by `location / { ... }` rather than `location /app2/ { ... }`.

What I don't understand is that how your **app1** can be workable without the similar

```
location /app1/ {
    try_files $uri /app1/index.html;
}
```

location block. Maybe it doesn't have an interactive part and used only as an API?

The next thing seems somewhat weird to me is your **app1**/**app2** API locations. You are using an URI suffix for the `proxy_pass` directive in your second location (`proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:5002/;`) and not using it at your first one (`proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:5001;`). That means a request like `/app1/api/endpoint` will appear to your **app1** as is, while request like `/app2/api/endpoint` will appear to your **app2** as `/endpoint`. If you'd use `proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:5001/app1/;` and `proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:5002/app2/;` both those requests would appear to your backends as `/api/endpoint`. You can find out more about this `proxy_pass` directive behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649885/a-little-confused-about-trailing-slash-behavior-in-nginx). However if both APIs works as expected, maybe your backend apps expect requests in that different form and you don't need to change anything. Nevertheless I think it is worth to mention that difference.

The last thing is about your other settings on proxying API requests. I've never seen any configuration to use `proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;` explicitly; the common method to keep connections to the upstream alive is to declare it using [`upstream`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) block with the [`keepalive`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive) parameter specified ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46772133/7121513)). The `proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;` most likely have been taken from the official WebSocket proxying [example](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) and makes no sense here without the rest of that configuration. More technical details about those HTTP headers and related subjects from MDN: [`Connection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection), [`Keep-Alive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive), [`Upgrade`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Upgrade). Disabling request/response buffering via `proxy_request_buffering off;` and `proxy_buffering off;` also seems strange to me when being applied to the API calls; usually it is used when you need some kind of real-time information about request/response progress which is unlikely for the API calls.